# How to turn off screensaver automatically when "do not disturb“ is on?

Tags: do-not-disturb

When I perform a task in "do not disturb" mode, I don't want also to be disturbed by a screensaver.

Can I automatically turn off the screensaver together with "do not disturb"? I.e. to configure it or to automate it by catching an event and triggering an action.

I know about Caffeine and similar apps, but it bothers me to configure both if only one button should be enough. Also some apps (and TV mirroring) start "do not disturb"“ automatically and I want the benefit of not being disturbed by a screensaver as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the mouse &/or keyboard, it won't, of course, go to screensaver.

If you're not, try System Prefs > Desktop & Screen Saver > Hot Corners.

I have mine set like this... just shove the cursor to the top left of the main screen & no more nodding off...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for tip. I am aware of these, but looking for automatic solution.
The point is „do not disturb“ is automatically turned on when „mirroring display“ and I need not to care about it at all. Contrary „hot corners“ are easy to hit accidentally, and easy to forget when you focus on the presenation topic..